# Set attribute of a function to be a specific equation that it fulfills

Tags: attributes

I would like to define a function f(x,y,z) by its attribute, namely by the specific equation `f(b,c,d)f(a,b+c,d)f(a,b,c)=f(a+b,c,d)f(a,b,c+d)` for all a,b,c,d.
Is it pssible to set this specific attribute to f?

Comment: Will this be used in simplifying expressions? You could perhaps use your constraint (expressed as an equation, using `==`) as an `Assumption` within `Simplify`. Can you provide some more context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`UpSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpSet.html)

```
f /: f[b_, c_, d_] f[a_, b_ + c_, d_] f[a_, b_, c_] = 
  f[a + b, c, d] f[a, b, c + d];

f[b, c, d] f[a, b + c, d] f[a, b, c]

(*  f[a, b, c + d] f[a + b, c, d]  *)

f[y, x, t] f[z, y + x, t] f[z, y, x]

(*  f[z, y, t + x] f[y + z, x, t]  *)
```

However, this won't work for numeric inputs that cause the additions to be carried out

```
f[2, 3, t] f[z, 2 + 3, t] f[z, 2, 3]

(*  f[2, 3, t] f[z, 2, 3] f[z, 5, t]  *)
```